# Verifying links that need authentication

Tags: c#, automation, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to verify all the links in a particular site in C# using the request-response technique. I noticed that none of the links are returning "OK". I zeroed in on the problem. The site requires authentication. Knowing this, how should I be going about it????

Here is my code sample:

```
WebRequest objWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse objHttpResponse;
try
{
        objWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strCheckingLink);
        objWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
        objHttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();
        if (objHttpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
        {}
        if (objHttpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
                httpSCode = (int)objHttpResponse.StatusCode;
                httpMsg = "OK";
                invalidLink = false;
        }
        else
        {
                invalidLink = true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your verification code to correctly verify your website's pages?

In this case, you need to authenticate yourself to your website programmatically. Since the authentication is usually done via cookies, you need to obtain the authentication cookie somehow, and then attach it to every your request.

Comment: Should I create the cookies programatically in my code or is there any other way?

Comment: you can't create an authentication cookie yourself (think of an intruder who doesn't authenticate to your site but rolls his own cookie instead). You need the website to hand the cookie to you.

Comment: I understand... but, if one has the proper credentials??? anyways, how can I get the cookie from the website??? Should I locate the cookie in my local machine once I log in manually? If yes, then how?

Comment: 1. You can pull the cookie out of your browser's storage. The method depends on your browser. For example, in Chrome you go to Developer tools -> Storage -> Cookies and you see the cookies.

Comment: 2. If you know the login/password to the website, you can programmatically POST them to the website's authentication page, and the website will give you the authentication cookie as part of the response.

Answer (score 0):

1, [Timeout (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) :
A Domain Name System (DNS) query may take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires resolution and you set Timeout to a value less than 15 seconds, it may take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown to indicate a timeout on your request.

2,Redirect : If a page redirected to another page ( status 301 and 302), HttpWebResponse will automatic get the finally page, so status is 200 (OK)

3, If page not found (404) or Server error (500) or other, will throw WebException